# Winstore not signed by microsoft?

Tags: windows-10

Winstore.app.exe is not signed. Virus total do not find any malware. Is winstore.app.exe unsigned for everyone?

Checked the signing with processexplorer. Win-10 home edition. Sha256:
8be2436a43384a463ad00961ac5cdc0c0a0471f1b9b1dd98aa689743051bc00a

Comment: What exactly is your question? Edit your question and clarify it.  UWP applications are required to be signed.  Suspect the problem is how you determined it wasn’t signed.  You shouldn’t even have permissions to the folder that contains that folder, furthermore, UWP applications don’t have a .exe extension.  Windows Store is a UWP application

Comment: [Seems this issue is known](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance-winpc/winstoreappexe-not-signed-by-microsoft/0a82a55d-1b23-4c87-8685-1c65533d49c9), without knowing the path to the executable, I am not willing to provide my knowledge on the subject.  I suspect the reason the executable isn't signed is for a good reason, the actual **Trusted Windows Store** application (Windows Store) is actually signed.